# Redirect won't work with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I got this warning

> Warning: You should not use `<Route component>` and `<Route render>` in the same route; `<Route render>` will be ignored

Not sure it's causing the Redirect to fail, but my code below just won't work, it's fine if this.isAuth is true, but not with `<Redirect />`

https://codesandbox.io/s/5xm202p1j4

```
render() {
    const { Component: component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          this.isAuth === false ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have destructured your props incorrectly, it should be `const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;`

The reason that it was giving you the warning was because you tried to destructure `Component` with uppercase `C` from props whereas you pass `component` as props to the authRoute, and not since `Component` is now present in `props` the `rest params` contains the component props which is passed down to the `Route`.

```
render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          this.isAuth === false ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

**[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j46w5joj4y)**

Comment: @ThianKianPhin, things such as these can be somtimes hard to find :-), the warning gives you a hint though